# Save a function in state and update it periodically

Tags: reactjs, firebase

The `getDocsRealtime()` adds a Firebase listener for a query and returns an unsubscribe function. In `componentDidMount`, this function loads top 5 documents initially. Every time the page is scrolled to bottom, this function is executed again to get the next 5 documents, and returns another unsubscribe function for the new documents. I want to make it so that:

unsubscribe function = old unsubscribe function + new unsubscribe function

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    let unsubscribe = await getDocsRealtime()
    this.setState({ unsubscribe })

    // Add Listener when page is scrolled to bottom
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollToBottom)
}

onScrollToBottom = async () => {

    if (window.scrollY > placeholderTop) {
        let unsubscribe = await getDocsRealtime()

        unsubscribe = () => {
            this.state.unsubscribe()
            unsubscribe()
        }

        this.setState({ unsubscribe })
    }
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {

    // Unsubscribe Listener
    this.state.unsubscribe && this.state.unsubscribe

    // Remove Listener for when page is scrolled to bottom
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollToBottom)
}
```

The problem I am having here is that instead of calling the old unsubscribe function, the program is calling the unsubscribe function stored in the state and I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time the page is scrolled to bottom, this function is executed
> again to get the next 5 documents

Since you want to query the database each time a specific event occurs in your front-end, i.e. the scrolling to the bottom, you should not, IMO, use a listener to query the database.

I would suggest you paginate the queries by "combining query cursors with the `limit()` method" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query). With this technique, each time the user scrolls down, you construct a new query starting at the last previously visible document and you execute it once (instead of continually "listening to it").

---

I understand that it seems interesting to combine realtime listening to the DB with pagination but in reality it can create weird situations when a document is shown twice in the front end because a new document has been added in the middle of a set of previously displayed docs.

Comment: Listener is needed because these documents are constantly being changed, if I only use pagination then those changes won't be visible to all users. That's why I have used pagination as well as Realtime listener. I have handled all the issues you mentioned so that's not the problem. I would just like to know how to concatenate new function with the old function.

Comment: I don't think you'll not be able to concatenate the unsuscribe functions. You could add the different unsuscribe functions to an Array and when you need to unsuscribe to all the listeners, loop over the Array and call the functions.

Comment: First sentence of the above comment should be "I don't think you'll be able to concatenate the unsuscribe functions."